# Visually Export MySQL Data to Different Schema

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, schema, legacy

I'm updating a legacy Rails application as well as its old database. The new app follows a slightly different schema and naming convention, as well as has different relationship types. I need to export the data from the old DB and map it to the newly named columns and tables. I realize I could manually write out `SELECT '...' AS '...'` for everything, but I was hoping to find a visual mapper that would tie to the two databases and maybe even have a logic layer between the two for cloning over the data. This is mostly because there are quite a few tables, and I feel like visually it'd be easier to keep track of what's going where and what I may or may not have missed. Is anyone familiar with software (Windows or Linux) that has such capability?

Comment: You want an ETL system? SSIS can do what you want.

Comment: sql Data Converter Tools selection - maybe db site?